# Shifting Output Image Down Gnuplot

Tags: macos, gnuplot, x11

I am typing this in textedit and load it into gnuplot later. When I do so the image is slightly off the top of the screen which means I can't see some of it. Is there a way to shift the entirety of the imaged produced down, or start the z-axis lower on the image?

Also, how do I make either my points or my lines black? Currently the lines for my sphere are red and the points are blue.

```
set pointsize 2
set tics
set border
unset key
set size ratio -1
set size square
unset xzeroaxis
unset yzeroaxis
unset zzeroaxis
# linetype linewidth 
set xrange[-1.2:1.2]
set yrange[-1.2:1.2]
set zrange[-1.2:1.2]
set view equal xyz
set xyplane at -1.2
set parametric
set isosamples 20
set hidden3d
set urange [0:2.0*pi]
set vrange [-pi/2:pi/2]
r=1.0;
# Parametric functions for the sphere
fx(v,u) = r*cos(v)*cos(u)
fy(v,u) = r*cos(v)*sin(u)
fz(v)   = r*sin(v)
splot fx(v,u),fy(v,u),fz(v),"mypoints" u 1:2:3 w p 3
```

Thanks, A.

Comment: as for the "How do I change the color" answer:  you need to set the linecolor:  `plot fx(v,y) w lines lc rgb "black"` or `... w lines lc rgb '#000000'`.  An alternative is to set a style:  `set style line 1 lc rgb "#000000"` and then:  `plot ... with lines ls 1`

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to change the colour of the points?

Comment: It's confusing syntax, but, `plot ... with points lc rgb "black"` should work too.

Comment: Yep that's perfect, thanks. Does anyone know about how to shift the picture more into view? Thanks.

Comment: You can do a transform (z -> z - z*):  `fz(v) = r*sin(v) - 3.` and then:  `"mypoints" u 1:2:($3 - 3.)`, but I don't know if that's what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so basically there are loads of issues that need solving so here goes:

1) Don't shift the picture down, get rid of the little tag end from the z part of the border. This makes the picture more central.

To do this: `set ticslevel 0.0`

2) Aspect ratio is not maintained in X11 so it looks all squashed. This is spoken about here:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3331162&group_id=2055&atid=102055

The workaround as they say is to set the size of window that X11 outputs to to be square, to do this: `set terminal x11 size 800,800`

3) Note, you don't now need: `set xyplane at -1.2` (or what ever z value you want) as this is taken care of using the set ticslevel command.

So now I have this:

```
set pointsize 2
set tics nomirror
set ticslevel 0.0
set border
set view equal xyz
unset key
unset xzeroaxis
unset yzeroaxis
unset zzeroaxis
# linetype linewidth 
set xrange[-1.2:1.2]
set yrange[-1.2:1.2]
set zrange[-1.2:1.2]
set parametric
set isosamples 20
unset hidden3d
set urange [0:2.0*pi]
set vrange [-pi/2:pi/2]
r=1.0;
# Parametric functions for the sphere
fx(v,u) = r*cos(v)*cos(u)
fy(v,u) = r*cos(v)*sin(u)
fz(v)   = r*sin(v)
splot fx(v,u) w lines lc rgb "black",fy(v,u) w lines lc rgb "black",fz(v) w lines lc rgb "black","mypoints" u 1:2:3 w points lc rgb "red" p 2
```

Hope this helps people in future.

Answer (score 0):

I shall try the transformation thing, but to try to explain my issue further just have a look at these pictures.

The first is what I get out when I run the code (now I have made everything black). The second is the same picture, but rotated (just by click, holding and moving the mouse around). As you can see on rotation the picture is off the screen. I just want the picture to be in the centre of the screen, I can't think why it wouldn't be.

Also why is there 1 or 1.5 of the z axis below the image? I don't really want that there either. Is there a way to set scales on x,y, and z axes equal? the set square thing has done it for x and y but as you can see the sphere is squished as well.

Thanks, A.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=k59gx&s=6

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2v9eo93&s=6

Note: I couldn't upload an image due to lack of rep, but I thought it would be the best way to illustrate my issue. The links show the images I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Running your script, omitting the reference to "mypoints", I get the plot you want without any extra z-axis or the top getting cut off. I'm using gnuplot v.4.4.3. What version are you using? Have you tried it without also plotting "mypoints"? There might be something in there affecting the plot. Also, you might want to explore coordinate mapping (try "help mapping" at the prompt) to plot datafiles in spherical coordinates.

Comment: I don't get any different if I remove the "mypoints" file. I am however running version: G N U P L O T
 Version 4.2 patchlevel 5 
 last modified Mar 2009
 System: Darwin 12.2.0

Comment: My issue is explained and it is apparently an X11 problem. You can see this by looking here:http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3566816&group_id=2055&atid=102055